# Saving whole data fetched using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, pagination

In this the csv file is not saving the whole data that is fetched. it's only saving the last page data

```
        df.to_csv('tribune1.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, pandas doesn't add new content to csv files, so when you save an existing file it can cause issues, to do that you need to use the append mode:

```
df.to_csv('tribune1.csv', mode='a', encoding='utf-8')
```